# User profiles not being created at sign up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

It seemed to be working quite well over the past few days but, since adding follow functionality, profiles are not created when they sign up. I read through the other questions like this one and I see things about using @reciever, do we have to use receivers? I followed a tutorial on how to allow profile creation at the time of sign up, the line goes as follows (I have a function I forgot about which should do the same thing)

```
# Wasn't commented out
User.profile = property(lambda u: CustomUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

# Wasn't commented out
def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        except:
            pass

# I had this saved( commented out ), are any of these correct?
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        CustomUserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

It's in my models.py but not inside of a function nor the profile class, is that my mistake or do we really have to use receivers? Forgive me, I've been teaching myself through tutorials and docs but alot of tutorials were deprecated (and I had no idea) so I just went off on my own and now i'm regretting it.

Comment: What you here do is "lazily" construct a `profile` when you access it, for example through `request.user.profile`. You do not "proactively" create one.

Comment: Oh! That makes alot more sense, do you perhaps have a link to a doc that could teach me how to do it properly? I'm trying to learn the basics and construct a crappy site then improve understanding by refining. Thank you for being so awesome!!! You've answered every problem I had, gonna put a little thank you in the site :D OOOF I forgot I have a function that seems like it would do the same. Added it to the question.

Comment: Looking things up about that and read a bit more about @receiver, should I be putting that in the CustomUser model in my users app? if so, do I have to call it in the create user function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the DB, all the **pycaches** and migrations (except init.py) and following this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

For some reason I had to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations profs` then migrate for it to make the tables. Not sure why, but it seems to work so far.